# Allow User Input Without Moving to New Line - Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

How can I let user enter in a value right after a string? For example, I want the user to be able to enter in
a value after this string on the same line "Please enter in the length of the first side: ". However, the 
`raw_input()` function starts at a new line. How can I continue on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input` [takes an argument](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).  So just do

```
raw_input('Please enter in the length of the first side: ')
```

and the user will be prompted to input right after the colon.